# How to tell if an Elasticsearch query result is based on all index data

Tags: elasticsearch

In the Elasticsearch query result data structure there is information on the number of shards that were queried. It looks e.g. like this:

> _shards: {total: 45, successful: 31, failed: 0}

Does this mean that the returned result set is potentially incomplete (because 45 > 31)?

Why is the number of failed shards not 14 (= 45 - 31 = total - successful)?

In some applications it is particularly important to get a result based on all shards, e.g. when aggregate functions are used for reporting. In such applications it is better to have no result at all than having a wrong result. So telling from the result if it is correct or not seems to me like a second best solution. It would be better to get no result at all instead a wrong one.

Comment: ES partitions all the data into n shards therefore a single shard does only contain fragments of the whole data. Do you want shards that do not contain anything related to your search to show up as successful or failing? But how do you decide then how many shards contributed to the result (a.k.a. had data related to the search terms)? This way you know that there are 45 shards of which 31 had data related to you search terms and none failed. Furhtermore, you're talking to the index and not to shards - they are managed by ES itself

Comment: Thanks Roman! I am still confused about the meaning of "successful" and "failed". Is there any documentation? To me it seems that "successful" is the number of shards with a "response" and not the number of shards containing data matching the query. That is, if part of my cluster is down due to a hardware failure and that part happened to contain primary and replica shards holding the same data, I will get "successful" < "total". But then, what does "failed" mean?